# Regex to match each line in a file, with windows and/or linux line break included, even for missing line break at EOF

Tags: performance, regex, posix

My requirement is to match each line of a text file, including the line terminator of each, at most excluding the terminator of the last line, to take into account the crippled, non POSIX-compiant files generated on Windows; each line terminator can be either `\n` or `\r\n`.

As a consequence, no character in the file should be left unmatched.

The best regex I could come up with is [this](https://regex101.com/r/SFqWEO/1):

```
\n|\r\n|[^\r\n]++(\r\n|\n)?
```

Is this the best I can write, performance-wise?

Please, if you use the `^`/`$` anchors or similar, comment about that, because their behavior is dependent on whether the engine considers them as multiline by default.

Comment: What is the regex engine you are using for this task? The best expression will depend on the regex flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
.*(\r?\n|$)
```

`.*` matches anything except line breaks (at least '\n', but some regex engines also treat other characters as line breaks).

`(\r?\n|$)` matches the line break or the end of the string (in case the last line is missing a line break.

Comment: This seems interesting. Any comment on the performances? Since you assume `.` is not matching line breaks, maybe `.*+` would improve the performance (as long as `.` doesn't match `\r` either).

Comment: I don't think using a possessive qualifier would speed things up in this case, because there shouldn't be any backtracking.  Maybe use `[^\r\n]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: no, no backtracking indeed, but the non possessive quantifier means that reach status is saved in case backtracking read needed. No?

Comment: I imagine that would depend on the implementation of the regex engine.  Best bet would be to test them and see which is faster.

Comment: This regex, however as one insidious flaw: it matches an empty string at the end of the file, as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/SFqWEO/2). This represents a major issue, as the number of matches is +1 the number of lines.

Comment: "there shouldn't be any backtracking": it depends on the regex flavor and even additional options. If it is Java, and `UNIX_LINES` flag is used, `.` also matches CR and there will be backtracking. Same thing concerns the .NET regex flavor, where `.` matches CR symbol. This can also happen in PCRE.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis is the last line guaranteed to have a line terminator? Can there be blank lines?

Comment: @RootTwo, no, the last line is _not_ guaranteed to have a line terminator; yes, there can be blank lines, but beware that _blank line_ means a line only containing the line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open),

> *newline* controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to
> text mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'. It works as
> follows:
>
> - When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or
>   '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to
>   the caller. If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line
>   endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the
>   other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given
>   string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.

IIUC, adding `newline=''` to `open` is what you need. To iterate over the file line by line, you could simply do `for line in f`. To read all lines at once, the [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) function could be used.

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("a\r\nb\nc")
with open("text.txt", "r", newline="") as f:
    print([line for line in f])
with open("text.txt", "r", newline="") as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Output:

```
['a\r\n', 'b\n', 'c']
['a\r\n', 'b\n', 'c']
```